# Adding a picture box to a form through a method

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make a recursive method which adds a picturebox to the form with an interval of 500 milliseconds, meaning, I would like every 500 milliseconds a new picturebox to appear on the form. However, the picture boxes appear only after the method has finished running (in my case 8 times). In other words, only after 4 seconds the picture boxes appeared, while I was expecting to see each one every 500 milliseconds.

Here's my recursive method:

```
public void QueenPos(bool[,] a,int x,int y,int c)
{
    for (int i = y; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
          **some code**

            PictureBox im = new PictureBox();                            
            im.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            im.Image = Image.FromFile(@"path");
            im.Size = new Size(40, 40);
            im.Location = new Point((x * 50) + 305, ((i * 50) + 55));
            Controls.Add(im);
            im.BringToFront();

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            QueenPos(a, x + 1, 0, c + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

If possible, I'd prefer not to uses a new thread which takes care of adding the picture box.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but this recursion seems flawed. You call QueenPos when you are inside a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was said above was right about not sleeping on the UI thread.

However, you might try the following instead of your `Thread.Sleep(500)` call

```
int count = 0
while(count++<10)
{
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Never sleep on the UI thread.

Instead, you should use a WinForms timer.

Comment: thanks... but how can i do so? i want also my method to halt for 500 milliseconds before moving onwards... should i add a timer solely for adding the the picturebox?

Comment: @ShaiYehezkel: In the timer's `Tick` handler, and one picture box, and increment a field in the form for the next tick.